# Remove comma if it starts a row in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose this is a column in a panda data frame:

```
,12022, 20230, 41454
431202, 20230, 41454
,34343, 1332, 445453
        ...
```

Is there a way to remove the comma that starts each row in a column?

```
df_new[column_name1] = df_new[column_name].remove_comma_if_starts_string
```

To get:

```
12022, 20230, 41454
431202, 20230, 41454
34343, 1332, 445453
        ...
```

Comment: do you need to search the entire dataframe or just a single column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str.lstrip(',')` for that. It "strips" the given string/character from the left. As opposed to `str.rstrip()`, which does it from the right. `str.strip()` does it on both left and right sides.

```
df_new[column_name1] = df_new[column_name].str.lstrip(',')
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`str.lstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) to remove leading chars that you don't want

```
>> ',12022, 20230, 41454'.lstrip(',') # strip() and rstrip() also exists
'12022, 20230, 41454'
```

On the dataframe it'll look like

```
df_new[column_name1] = df_new[column_name].str.lstrip(',') # you may use same name of column
```